# Symfony 2.8 : Edit service config

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I'm trying to edit or override the config (admin_orm.xml) of a service (sonata.user.admin.user) which is created by SonataUserBundle. I'd like to be able to use the entitymanager in that service. Because i need to edit edit on another entity after the creation of a new user on SonataAdminBundle (https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/saving_hooks.html).

The config file:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="sonata.user.admin.groupname">sonata_user</parameter>
</parameters>

<services>
    <service id="sonata.user.admin.user" class="%sonata.user.admin.user.class%">
        <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="%sonata.user.admin.groupname%" label="users" label_catalogue="SonataUserBundle" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore" />
        <argument />
        <argument>%sonata.user.admin.user.entity%</argument>
        <argument>%sonata.user.admin.user.controller%</argument>
        <call method="setUserManager">
            <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager" />
        </call>
        <call method="setTranslationDomain">
            <argument>%sonata.user.admin.user.translation_domain%</argument>
        </call>
    </service>

    <service id="sonata.user.admin.group" class="%sonata.user.admin.group.class%">
        <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="%sonata.user.admin.groupname%" label="groups" label_catalogue="SonataUserBundle"  label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore" />
        <argument />
        <argument>%sonata.user.admin.group.entity%</argument>
        <argument>%sonata.user.admin.group.controller%</argument>
        <call method="setTranslationDomain">
            <argument>%sonata.user.admin.group.translation_domain%</argument>
        </call>
    </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix my problem which is this line:

```
$em = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

it's probably not the cleanest way to fix the problem, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you sound copy the service Definition and deactivate the boxed fosuserbundle service.

To omit Code duplications you could extend from the original service.

Define the menu entries in your config.yml to exclude the native admin Services.

Comment: First of all thanks for your replay and yes i already tried to copy the service definition but i get an errors like : Cannot automatically determine base route name, please define a default baseRouteName value for the admin class.. It's maybe because i must desactivate the boxed service, but how can i do that ?

Comment: I don't know about a functionality like disabling services in symfony out of the box. But I think you can simply create a compiler pass to overwrite your Container definitions. Look at this example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html

define that compiler pass in your ChildMediaBundle see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html